# How do I loop a function after receiving user input?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie and am working on this Dictionary program. After receiving a word the program retrieves the definition and then the program ends. How do I get the program to loop back to receive another input?

I've tried using a while True: but it doesn't seem to work...thanks!

```
**data = json.load(open("Teaching/data.json"))
**def dictionary(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if word in data:
       return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys()))>0:
        yn = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter 'Y' for yes, 'N' for no: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        if yn == 'Y':
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif yn == 'N':
            return "The word doesn't exist. Please try again!"
        else:
           return "I don't understand."
    else:
       return ("Please try again.")
word = input("Enter a word: ")
output = dictionary(word)
if type(output) == list:
    for item in output:
        print(item)
else:
    print(output)****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the `while` loop. After receiving an input it will go through the full code, then will wait for another input and that goes in infinity. Note that the `input()` must be under the `while True:`

```
def dictionary(word):
        word = word.lower()
        if word in data:
           return data[word]
        elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys()))>0:
            yn = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter 'Y' for yes, 'N' for no: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
            if yn == 'Y':
                return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
            elif yn == 'N':
                return "The word doesn't exist. Please try again!"
            else:
               return "I don't understand."
        else:
           return ("Please try again.")
while True:
        word = input("Enter a word: ")
        output = dictionary(word)
        if type(output) == list:
            for item in output:
                print(item)
        else:
            print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was putting it in the wrong place...I'll try and figure out why I had it wrong!

Comment: @WilliamCrutcher can you please upvote my answer, please? :)

Comment: for sure, It's says because I'm new it won't let my upvote be public though...